# how to fix objects are not valid as a React child, in Nextjs13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

How to fix this error in Nextjs13, *objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead*

I'm fetching data from Supabase via Prisma, and I'm getting the data in my terminal but also I'm getting the error in my next App.

`pages/index.tsx`

```
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import RestaurantCard from "@/components/Restaurantcard";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma =new PrismaClient()

const fetchRestaurant = async () => {
  const restaurants = await prisma.restaurant.findMany();
  return restaurants;
};

export default async function Home() {
  const restaurants = await fetchRestaurant();
  console.log({restaurants})
  return (
    <main className="bg-gray-100 min-h-screen">
      <main className="max-w-screen-2xl m-auto bg-white">
        <Navbar />
        <main>
          <Header />
          <div className="py-3 px-36 mt-10 flex flex-wrap justify-center">
            {restaurants.map((res) => (
              <RestaurantCard />
            ))}
          </div>
        </main>
      </main>
    </main>
  );
}
```

`Data which I'm getting in the terminal`

```
{
  restaurants: [
    {
      id: 25,
      name: 'Vivaan - fine Indian',      
    },
    {
      id: 26,
      name: 'RamaKrishna Indian',
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us `<RestaurantCard />`?

Comment: Grover actually, even if i comment that full map div then also I'm getting the same error, although I'm getting the data in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you want to traverse the restaurants received from API and render a component with those.

The issue here is that you are trying to map out the object instead of the actual array inside it.
The data received is an object.
I have added 2 images showing how you are doing it vs how it should be done to get things working.

[Mapping array from the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssarJ.png)

```
restaurants.restaurants.map((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

[Mapping the object instan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAYHO.png)

```
restaurants.map((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

Thank you
Kindly Mark this answer correct if it helped :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sriesh, the thing is even if i comment that full map div then also I'm getting the same error, although I'm getting the data in my terminal

Comment: Oh, Can you send the exact error screenshot, it can help clarify the problem. Also, try putting in the function call inside useEffect hook 

UseEffect(() => { <ENTERCODE> } , [] );

Comment: This is the error I'm getting,                                                                                 
 **Server Error**
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6179:11)